# Cruise Control: Web-based Source Control Configuration

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, config

Currently I have this sourcecontrol config block.

```
    <sourcecontrol type="svn">
      <trunkUrl>https://SampleSVNOnlineRepository.com/12maksdde12d123ede12</trunkUrl>
 
      <workingDirectory>c:\MyProject</workingDirectory>
 
      <username>admin</username>
      <password>mypassword</password>
 
    </sourcecontrol>
```

Cruise Control Exception:

`Source control failure : Unable to execute file [c:\MyProject\svn]. The file may not exist or may not be executable.]`

What seems to be the problem here?

Comment: This does not look like a CruiseControl configuration file. It looks more like CruiseControl.NET.

Answer (score 4):

It means that CruiseControl.NET cannot find the svn executable. You'll have to specify it with the `executable` element, e.g:

```
<sourcecontrol type="svn">
...
    <executable >absolute\path\tp\subversion\executable</element>
```

Comment: the svn repository is on the internet and not in the machine where Cruise Control is located..

Comment: executable actually means the program SVN, not the repository

Comment: @Pondidum Thanks, I thought it was obvious, from the documentation of the element, but obviously it was not :)

Comment: @Fleents: One thing is the subversion repository itself - where the code resides - but CruiseControl.NET needs the _program_ svn in order to be able to check out the sources, look for diffs, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Did you checkout the project first by hand in that location? As I understood when I played with phpUnderControl, which uses CruiseControl, [you do the first checkout by hand](http://www.phpundercontrol.org/documentation/getting-started.html).